# URL Scheme for switching between 3G and 4G

Tags: ios, url

Just wondering if there is a URL scheme to switch between 3G and 4G networks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not appear to be about Apple hardware or software within the scope defined in the [help centre](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @tetsujin Questions about *using* URL schemes are on-topic

Answer (score 2):

Do you have an app called Launcher?

> Launcher with Notification Center Widgets by Cromulent Labs
>   https://appsto.re/gb/iLR81.i

You can create a custom URL Scheme and add it to your Today Widget

[image: Add New]
[image: Custom Launcher]

Paste the below into the URL textbox and give it a name.

Cellular/Mobile Data:

```
prefs:root=MOBILE_DATA_SETTINGS_ID
```

This gets you to the "Mobile Data" section.

I'll see if there is a path to "Mobile Data Options" -> "Voice & Data"

---

See this post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8246070
You could try getting to the settings page for the network

Comment: Good point. I thought it was best not to copy paste but as you say if it were to change on the answer it would be gone

Comment: Added a more detailed answer

Answer (score 1):

iOS 10 Update, its now

> App-prefs

Not

> prefs

So use

```
App-prefs:root=MOBILE_DATA_SETTINGS_ID
```

You can see more at

https://gist.github.com/deanlyoung/368e274945a6929e0ea77c4eca345560

I'd advise using **Workflow** which was recently acquired by Apple

> Workflow by Apple
>   https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/workflow/id915249334?mt=8